# Duration of individual methods (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, debugging, profiling

Is there some kind of tool/plugin (preferably for eclipse) that would allow me to determine how much time each method of my code is taking or something along those lines? Or perhaps determine what is taking an unusually large amount of time? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Regarding your preference, it depends on which version of Eclipse you're using. Check out this post in the parallel site: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/76053/52980

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [The Eclipse Test & Performance Tools Platform (TPTP)](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-TPTP-Profiling-Tool/tptpProfilingArticle.html) - it allows you to profile all methods entered for a single execution. It is a very un-intrusive method - it does not force you to make code changes.

Here are [the install instructions.](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Install_TPTP_with_Update_Manager)

**Edit:** It seams, that [TPTP is not available after Eclipse Helios](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/project_info/devplans/EclipseTPTPProjectPlan2010.htm). You can use VisualVM as an stand-alone profiler. If you want Eclipse integration, there is the tool [JVM Monitor](http://www.jvmmonitor.org/index.html), but I have note used that.

Comment: @A.R.S. No, just for Helios, I edited my answer to include that.

Answer (score 2):

For these kind of tasks, you could use a profiler like VisualVM.

Answer (score 1):

[JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) also offers an eclipse plugin that lets you profile your run configurations directly from the eclipse IDE. The results are shown in the JProfiler window, but source code navigation from the JProfiler goes back to eclipse. You can see this in action in [this screen cast](http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2009/06/jprofilers-ide-integrations.html).

If you're looking for a performance bottleneck, you should start with the "Hot spots" view in the CPU section. This will show you the methods where most time is spent.

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler